# Jetty LdapLoginModule: Login Failure: all modules ignored

Tags: java, security, web-applications, jetty, openldap

I'm getting the below on trying to submit a login form. Does anyone know what causes this? Thanks.

```
2012-10-13 13:11:46.300:INFO:oejpjs.LdapLoginModule:Searching for users with filter: '(&(objectClass={0})({1}={2}))' from base dn: ou=people,dc=my-domain,dc=com
2012-10-13 13:11:46.307:INFO:oejpjs.LdapLoginModule:Found user?: true
2012-10-13 13:11:46.311:WARN:oejpj.JAASLoginService:
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Login Failure: all modules ignored
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:921)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.JAASLoginService.login(JAASLoginService.java:238)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator.validateRequest(FormAuthenticator.java:209)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:491)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:937)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:998)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:856)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

FWIW this is some of the peripheral configuration:

jetty.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configure>
    <Call name="addBean">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.JAASLoginService">
                <Set name="name">ldap</Set>
                <Set name="loginModuleName">ldaploginmodule</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

ldap.conf:

```
ldaploginmodule {
    org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.spi.LdapLoginModule required
    debug="true"
    contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
    hostname="localhost"
    port="389"
    bindDn="cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
    bindPassword="secret"
    authenticationMethod="simple"
    forceBindingLogin="false"
    userBaseDn="ou=people,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
    userRdnAttribute="uid"
    userIdAttribute="uid"
    userPasswordAttribute="userPassword"
    userObjectClass="inetOrgPerson"
    roleBaseDn="ou=groups,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
    roleNameAttribute="cn"
    roleMemberAttribute="uniqueMember"
    roleObjectClass="groupOfUniqueNames";
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the exact same problem. The fix I found [here](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg00398.html), is to change the `forceBindingLogin` to `"true"`, in the `ldap.conf`.

I wish I had a clear explanation for this :-(

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instructions here exactly?

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/JAAS

one quick difference is:

`<Set name="[L]oginModuleName">ldaploginmodule</Set>`

also, did you use the proper cli option pointing to the actual location of the file?

-Djava.security.auth.login.config=ldap.conf

Comment: Thanks, I've tried a few tutorials which I guess is how the case difference made it in, but that doesn't seem to affect it haven't made the change. One difference is that I'm using the maven plugin. I'm passing the java.security.auth.login.config arg to maven which must be working as it is hitting LDAP (everything looks successful though).

Comment: I believe [this is you](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg00398.html). Could you provide an explanation for why this works.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine after creating system user and assigned all permission on /content folder.